# Dividing with double, 0 as a result?

Tags: java

So it is obvious  that

```
 int x = 3/4; // x is 0 here
```

But i do not understand why the following is also the case:

```
double x = 3/4; // x is also 0 here
```

With the following i am able to get the result i want:

```
 double x = (double) 3/4; // x is 0.75 here, but why do i have to cast?
```

Comment: `double x = 3/4; ` is still integer division. the receiver type doesn't change anything in the computation.

Comment: Actually java promotes Integer for integer type of computations. That's why you need to cast.

Comment: `3/4` is integer (integer divided by integer). Assigning it to a double doesn't change that fact. That's why 3/4 is always 0. However `(double) 3/4` is double (double divided by integer).